# $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^2 (1+x)^k (1-x)^{n-k}$ as a function of $(1-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, summation, binomial-distribution

I am trying to show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^2 (1+x)^k (1-x)^{n-k}$$ can be expressed explicitly as a function of $(1-x^2)$.

I am wondering where to start with this, as anything I have tried has not gone very far!

Thank you!

Comment: $1-x^2$ is a function of $x^2$, and $x^2$ is a function of $|x|$.  So you are trying to show that the value of the expression does not depend on the sign of $x$, i.e., it is an even function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you assume $k<\frac n2$, then $n-k>k$ and you have a summand of $\binom nk^2(1-x^2)^k(1-x)^{n-2k}$

If $k=\frac n2$ you just get $\binom{n}{\frac n2}^2(1-x^2)^{\frac n2}$

What about when $k>\frac n2$?